# Any policy on "beating a dead horse"?

Tags: discussion

Today, I saw the resurfacing of [an almost two-year old question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/89744/button-for-play-but-from-beginning-for-a-scrubber-ux). This question had already received 20 answers when the OP offered a `+100` bounty, stating the following reason:

> This question has not received enough attention.

20 answers is more than what 99.87% of the questions on this site have received.

Additionally, it's a pretty blatant icon request...

> What should the symbol be?

My thinking is that there's likely not a lot of value for the community in having this question resurface. Obviously the community discourages digging up old questions to make insignificant grammatical fixes or retags because every action bumps these to the top and new questions get pushed down.

**So, how should these situations get handled?** Should I just move on because offering bounty on a stale, thoroughly answered question is the OP's prerogative, should I vote to close a 2-year-old question as off-topic (requesting icon suggestion), or what?

*Are we okay with bounties reviving dead questions indefinitely?*

Comment: and the funny thing is that the worst possible solution has been given a bounty and has been marked as the answer :P

Comment: And shouldnt it be off topic? It’s basically an icon request without the word icon involved.

Comment: @dennislees Absolutely. I'm honestly not sure why it's still open, given how eager this community tends to be with closing those types of questions..